# data returned from php function not being detected by if function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the following function which acts on an AJAX query:

```
    var formData = $(this).serialize(); //put the form names and values into an array called formdata
    $.get('filtertest.php',formData,processData); //jquery ajax call

    function processData(data){
        if(data =="a"){
        $('#content').html("<h2>You have not selected any 'types of dwelling'. Please select at least one.</h2>");
        $('#linky').hide();
        }
        else if(data=="b"){
        $('#content').html("<h2>You have not selected any 'style of dwelling'. Please select at least one.</h2>");
        $('#linky').hide();
        }
        else if(data=="c"){
        $('#content').html("<h2>You have not selected any 'situation of dwelling'. Please select at least one.</h2>");
        $('#linky').hide();
        }
        else if(data==1){
        $('#content').html('<h2>There is ' + data + ' property available!</h2>');
        $('#linky').show();
        }
        else if(data==0){
        $('#content').html('<h2>There are no properties available, please expand your search options.</h2>');
        $('#linky').hide();
        }
        else{
        $('#content').html('<h2>There are ' + data + ' properties available!</h2>');
        $('#linky').show();
        }
    }//end processData
```

In the filtertest.php file, the following code is used to check if none of the field values are entered, and if so returns the letter a:

```
//if none of the TODs are selected, returns an error
if ($_GET[tod_house]==0 && $_GET[tod_bung]==0 && $_GET[tod_flat]==0 && $_GET[tod_barnc]==0 && $_GET[tod_farm]==0 && $_GET[tod_small]==0 && $_GET[tod_build]==0 && $_GET[tod_devland]==0 && $_GET[tod_farmland]==0 ){
echo "a";
return;
}
```

However in the initial ajax function `processData` the line beginning`if(data =="a"){` isnt catching the value echoed - its going all the way down to the final `else` function. The strange thing is the letter 'a' is input into the html in this final `else` function, meaning the echo is correct and the filtertest.php file is returning immediatly - its just not being caught by the `if` function testing for the letter 'a'.

There must be some syntax error here but Ive been looking at it for the last hour trying different things and I cant work it out, its starting to really annoy me!!

---

### edit

After changing the daft error pointed out below, it still wasnt working. I tried echoing a different number instead of a letter. I changed 'a' in both `processData` and `filtertest.php` to '-1' and HEY PRESTO! it works. So it is an error with the string containing 'a' - am I getting the comparison of two strings wrong in the javascript function?

Comment: Technically that's not returning "a" it's echoing "a" and returning `null`

Comment: Fix your PHP first. `$_GET[tod_house]` is invalid and will generate warnings about using undefined constants. Your output won't be just "a", it'll be a ton of PHP warnings with an 'a' tagged on to the end.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you try to access your data in the `$_GET` array: keys should be strings, i.e.

```
$_GET['tod_house']
```

not

```
$_GET[tod_house]
```

More precision coming from [Marc B' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22056241/data-returned-from-php-function-not-being-detected-by-if-function/22056284#comment33444074_22056241): the output won't be just `a` and thus won't be picked.

Comment: Stupid, stupid error! however the problem persists even after fixing this. I find it strange that only the single 'a' is shown in the html on the final 'else' function - surely this means this is the only thing returned from the php file so the first 'if' function should pick up on it?

Comment: please see my edit - im closing in on a solution! :)

Comment: I don't really have any other idea for the cause; however you can try and see if there wouldn't be some other characters by putting something like `console.log("'" + data + "'");` before all your conditions (i.e. logging what's in data between simple quotes to see if there's some blank chars)